# Join 2 list <t> one as a sub-list of the other

Tags: c#, list

I have two list that have been returned from two separate tables in a SQL server database using dapper lstPart and lstSite. Both lists have a ITEMNUM field which correspond with each other. In the part list the ITEMNUM field is unique but in the Site list it is not. Some parts have multiple sites some have none.

```
using System;

namespace CWIC_Data_Framework.Definition.MP2Definitions
{
    public class MP2BaseTableDefinition

    {
        public string ITEMNUM { get; set; }
        public string? DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string? NOTES { get; set; }
        public string? UOM { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DATEADDED { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LASTEDITDATE { get; set; }
        public string? COMMENTS { get; set; }
        public string? SITE { get; set; }
        public string? LOCATION { get; set; }
        public int? QTYONHAND { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;

namespace CWIC_Data_Framework.Definition.MP2Definitions
{
    public class MP2SiteTableDefinition

    {
        public string ITEMNUM { get; set; }
        public int? REORDERPOINT { get; set; }
        public int? REORDERQTY { get; set; }
        public string? SITE { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LASTDATECOUNTED { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LASTDATERCVD { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LASTACTIVITY { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am creating an app with C# WPF and I would like to have a final result similar to this.
[Example Of What I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKnCz.png)

I think I need to create a single list that contains the site list as a sublist to the parts list using LINQ and then bind it to a Datagrid but I am not positive.

```
    public class Part
    {
        public int PartID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public list<site> Location { get; set; }
   }
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Here is the class for calling one of the list (The part list) , the other is the same.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using CWIC_Data_Framework.Definition.MP2Definitions;
using Dapper;
using SerilogTimings;

namespace CMMS_Status.Data
{
    internal class MP2BaseTableData

    {
        private static string ThisMethod;
        private string ThisClass;

        public List<MP2BaseTableDefinition> ListOfMp2Base(Dictionary<string, object> paramDictionary)
        {
            ThisMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            using (var op = Operation.Begin("{Class}{Method}", ThisClass, ThisMethod))

            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionValue("CreeMesRtp")))
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters(paramDictionary);
                var SQL = @"
                            Select
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.ITEMNUM,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.DESCRIPTION,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.UOM,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.NOTES,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.DATEADDED,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.LASTEDITDATE,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVCOMM.COMMENTS,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_STOCK.SITE,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_STOCK.LOCATION,
                            CMMSSB.MP2_STOCK.QTYONHAND
                            From
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVY Inner Join
                            CMMSSB.MP2_STOCK On CMMSSB.MP2_STOCK.ITEMNUM = CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.ITEMNUM Left Join
                            CMMSSB.MP2_INVCOMM On CMMSSB.MP2_INVCOMM.ITEMNUM = CMMSSB.MP2_INVY.ITEMNUM
                            ";

                var Output = connection.Query<MP2BaseTableDefinition>(SQL, parameters).ToList();
                op.Complete();
                return Output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class for pulling the Site info.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using CMMS_Status.Definition;
using CWIC_Data_Framework.Definition.MP2Definitions;
using Dapper;
using SerilogTimings;

namespace CMMS_Status.Data
{
    internal class MP2SiteTableData

    {
        private static string ThisMethod;
        private string ThisClass;

        public List<MP2SiteTableDefinition> ListOfMp2Site(Dictionary<string, object> paramDictionary)
        {
            ThisMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            using (var op = Operation.Begin("{Class}{Method}", ThisClass, ThisMethod))

            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionValue("CreeMesRtp")))
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters(paramDictionary);
                var SQL = @"
                        Select
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.ITEMNUM,
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.REORDERPOINT,
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.REORDERQTY,
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.LASTDATECOUNTED,
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.LASTDATERCVD,
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO.LASTACTIVITY
                        From
                        CMMSSB.MP2_SITEINFO
                        ";

                var Output = connection.Query<MP2SiteTableDefinition>(SQL, parameters).ToList();
                op.Complete();
                return Output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, your solutions seems to write. In improvement you can make the list as ICollection.such as public ICollection<Site> Locations {  get; set; } can you exlplain further that for which part you are confused?

Comment: Could you post your data access part. Because this is very common use case. If you provide more code snippet, we could help you.

Comment: I am not sure how to actually combine the list in the way I am looking. So what would the  LINQ syntax be to combine the two list.. Also I have the first two classes defined which is what I use to pull the data with Dapper, Do I need to create the class that houses the list of locations as well or instead of the two separate classes?

Comment: @Frank are you looking for a "group by"? So for every Part in the Parts List you want a collection of Sites that you can access from that Part?

Comment: Dapper doesn't really handle relationships, but I think you could get what you want with either multimap or just manually doing a join. Where does `PartID` come from?

Answer (score -1):

Update: I have checked the below code

But why you changed full description??

```
  public class Site
{
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

}

public class Part
{
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Site> Location { get; set; }
}
var siteList = new List<Site>() {
            new Site{PartID = 1, Location = "Dhaka"},
            new Site{PartID = 2, Location = "Rajshahi"},
            new Site{PartID = 3, Location = "Khulna"},
            new Site{PartID = 2, Location = "Barisal"},
            new Site{PartID = 1, Location = "Narsingdi"},
        };
        var dictionary = siteList.GroupBy(s => s.PartID)
              .ToDictionary(s => s.Key,
                 s => s.ToList());

        var partList = new List<Part> (){
            new Part{ PartID  = 3, Description = "A", Location = null},
            new Part{ PartID  = 2, Description = "C", Location = null},
            new Part{ PartID  = 1, Description = "B", Location = null},
        };


        foreach(var part in partList)
        {
            part.Location = dictionary[part.PartID];
        }
```

Comment: A `Dictionary` is definitely not what is needed for this.

Comment: I have added the full code @NetMage after testing.